# JQuery focus on TextBox or Div

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am working on a project,i have a div in which i have multiple divs, each div have unique ID(from DB) and each div contains a textbox for adding comment
like below

```
<div id="maindiv">
<div id="@item.resid">
<p>Content1</p>
<input type="text" class="txtarea" resourceid="@item.resid"/>
</div>
<div id="@item.resid">
<p>Content2</p>
<input type="text" class="txtarea" resourceid="@item.resid"/>
</div>
<div id="@item.resid">
<p>Content3</p>
<input type="text" class="txtarea" resourceid="@item.resid"/>
</div>
<div id="@item.resid">
<p>Content4</p>
<input type="text" class="txtarea" resourceid="@item.resid"/>
</div>
```

.
.
.
.

i am adding comment by keypress event of textbox, the problem i am having is that when i add comment on content at downside, then after adding the focus comes on top.
I have tried focusing on textbox and even on div but not worked :(
below is my code of adding comment

```
$(".txtarea").keypress(function (e) {
            if (e.keyCode == 13) {
                if ($(this).val().trim() != "") {
                    var commentText = $(this).val();
                    var resourceid = $(this).attr('resourceid');
                    var divId = "." + resourceid;
                    $.ajax({
                        url: ResourceAjaxUrl.AddNewCommentOnResources,
                        type: "POST",
                        data: JSON.stringify({ resourceID: resourceid, commentText: commentText }),
                        dataType: "html",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset-utf-8",
                        success: function (Result) {
                                    $('#maindiv').html(Result);
                                    $('#maindiv div#' + divId.split('.')[1]).focus();
                                    $('#maindiv div#' + divId.split('.')[1]).find(".txtarea").focus();                                    

                        },
                        error: function (msg) {
                            alert("Unable to save comment in");
                        }
                    });
                }
                else {
                    $(this).val('');
                    $(this).focus();
                }
            }
        });
```

i've seen focus() line on developer tool, its working fine but still not focusing, i want that if i add comment on downside(or last) comment, the focus will stay on that instead of going on top

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't set a focus on a div. It is for form elements (inputs, textareas, buttons etc.) only.

Looks like your problem is that you have wrong ID in selector when trying to find a `.txtarea`:

```
success: function (Result) {
                                    $('#maindiv').html(Result);
                                    $('#maindiv div#' + divId.split('.')[1]).find(".txtarea").focus();                                    

                        },
```

> $('**#main** div#' + divId.split('.')[1]).find(".txtarea").focus();

replaced with

> $('**#maindiv** div#' + divId.split('.')[1]).find(".txtarea").focus();

Besides, once you have a unique ID, you do not need to write `$('#maindiv div#' + divId.split('.')[1])`. This is enough: `$('#' + divId.split('.')[1])` (id must be unique for a whole page anyway, so no need to specify that it is a `div` located inside `#maindiv`)

Comment: Sir, in this line  $('#main div#' + divId.split('.')[1]).find(".txtarea").focus();  i have tried focusing on text box

Comment: ID is appearing as per expected, i've checked it on Firebird :)

Comment: @SyedSalmanRazaZaidi check your code. I understand what you are trying to do, but in your HTML there is div with ID #maindiv, but you search `div#' + divId.split('.')[1]` inside `#main` instead of inside `#maindiv`. Read carefuly what is replaced with what below first block of code.

Comment: i am searching for div with id  divId.split('.')[1] and that div is inside maindiv

Comment: Yes! Inside `#maindiv`, not inside `#main`! , but in your question, it is speicified that you are searching inside a div with ID `#main`. This line `$('#main div#' + divId.split('.')[1]).find(".txtarea").focus(); ` from your code. It tells jQuery to search inside `#main`, not inside `#maindiv` like it should be. That is what I'm trying to tell you about.

Comment: yes my mistake, it's typing mistake, in my code i have maindiv instead of main,but still not working :(

Comment: See demo: http://jsfiddle.net/PmmRW/1/ It works there. Maybe you have something that throws your focus on a top input after success executed? Besides, there is no `type="textbox"`, even if it works (just because browser can't recognize it and use default value which is text) - it is not valid. You should have `type="text"`